Please help with the Community Evaluation
We are in a period of Community Evaluation to assess the quality of our site. We need users to review the questions and answers to get sufficient feedback about where we stand.
There are 10 questions that have been randomly selected. Each question will have one or more answers. Simply mark whether the information reflects what we want this site to represent.
If you want to participate, be honest! Don't mark everything as excellent just because you love Quant.SE. Consider the litmus test as: could you find better information via Google on another site?

The results are in!
The question with the highest ranking was Understanding Passive Rebate Arbitrage, which I happened to answer. :)
The question most consistently ranked as "satisfactory" was How to attribute income that incurs a double liability in a P&L? Not exactly a quant question, but it did have some useful information.
The question with the lowest ranking was Collecting Data such as the relationship data from http://investing.businessweek.com. I have put this out of its misery.
It should be no surprise that the questions that fared the best were the ones that actually reflect what quants do.
